# How to Mock "this"

Tags: java, junit, powermock

when I test a class's constructor there is an sentence like:

```
 SAPPublisherSvc server = new SAPPublisherSvc(sdkApp, this, curInt, factory, tidHandler);
```

I want to use `PowerMock.expectNew()`, but what can I fill to instead of the parameter `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem ,here is what you should do:

```
PowerMock.expectNew(SAPPublisherSvc.class,EasyMock.same(app),EasyMock.isA(ServiceComponent.class) ,EasyMock.same(curInt),EasyMock.same(factory),EasyMock.same(tidHandler)).andReturn(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a keyword denoting the [innermost "enclosing" object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3). In other words, the object you're currently in.

Since it's just an object reference (for this purpose, like a variable or a field), if you want to create a mock of an instance of this object's class, just use:

`createMock(this.getClass());`